# Android dev: webview more like full browser?

Tags: android, webview

Does anyone know of an existing project or open source class which makes a webview more like the regular browser, specifically for popup windows, new browser windows, javascript alerts, launching certain intents when clicking on certain links (email, youtube, etc)?  In short, behaving more like the system's web browser.

I am aware of the various ways one might wire all those things together, and in fact I am planning to do just that.  But before I started, I wanted to make sure there isn't something already out there that I could use.

Thanks,
Richard